# What is the fastest protocol for downloading files from a server on the internet

Tags: networking, ftp, bittorrent, protocol, network-protocols

I have over 100GBs worth of files on a server sitting on a dedicated 1GBs port. Our office sits on a 100MBs port. Each of the archive files are about 1-5GBs each.

What protocol would be the fastest way to download these files?

I was thinking that a direct HTTP connection would be best over FTP or BitTorrent.

Comment: calculate the theoretical limit, test HTTP, see how close you are to the theoretical limit.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [For file transfer, does ftp perform better than http?](http://superuser.com/questions/176324/for-file-transfer-does-ftp-perform-better-than-http)

Comment: This depends on many factors, so there isn't really a silver-bullet answer to give you (as discussed in the linked duplicate).  What have your tests shown to be fastest in your scenario?

Comment: I've found setting up a bittorrent service and using bittorrent to be faster so far.

Comment: I'd personally go with SCP due to security, and compression if both ends can cope with it...

Comment: dunno but it might be more a question of quickest way, though I don't know that either.. Your question is ok though you've framed  it a bit like a theoretical whereas in practise the question might be more of a practical thing, of this way works faster for whatever reason not purely based on protocol.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FTP and HTTP are both straight TCP streams once the transfer starts. So they're equivalent, especially if you don't have a lot of small files (per-file overhead doesn't matter when you have mostly huge files).

HTTP/2 does a good job of sending multiple files simultaneously over the same TCP stream, which "keeps the pipe full", rather than having a brief bubble of zero throughput between files. HTTP (including HTTP/2) also offers byte-range requests so you can resume interrupted downloads.

Comment: Bittorrent only provides an advantage if there are multiple others that you want to download the file from.  A 1-to-1 transfer over Bittorrent won't be faster than HTTP or FTP.

Comment: bittorrent does provide checksumming